# android: most efficient way to repeat an image

Tags: android, image, png

I am doing a project where I want 100 of the same image randomly scattered throughout the screen.  In the future, I want an image to disappear when the image is tapped by the user.

I am mainly focusing right now on the most efficient way to display a repeated image.  It seems like I could set it up so that the fact that the images are the same makes it more efficient;  I'm just not sure how.  I do not want to proceed further until I know I have a sound base.  I'm using .png files.

I've looked around without a definite answer.

Also, would if be easier to draw my object with two circles (which is what my image is), rather than using a bitmap?

Any clues???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about drawing the bitmap on a `Canvas` object, the method should be pretty straightforward. You load the image into a `Bitmap` object and keep it as a member of the owning class, and draw it 100 times using `canvas.drawBitmap(...)` functions.

The other way of doing it is having 100 ImageViews with the same image, but I won't even write the details because this would be truly inefficient!

Comment: I think you're confused. When talking about drawing and having images in memory you use a bitmap object which is different from the bitmap file format (.bmp). A jpg, png, and other formats are loaded in memory as bitmaps.

Comment: So I can put my png files in the res drawable folders and not need to change anything?

Comment: Yes, you can put it there, or in the assets folder.

Comment: Bitmap bit_dot = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dot_catch);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();canvas.drawBitmap(bit_dot, 100, 100, null);  Not sure why not working.  Anyone, help?

Comment: You're drawing on a canvas that you created, so... nothing happens because you haven't told anyone what that canvas is about. You need to have a custom View object, there you must override the `onDraw()` method, this method will be called for you and provides you with a Cavnas object to draw on. You're almost there my friend!

Comment: Hey, I tried to do what you suggested, but I am not sure if I did it right (I don't think I did it right).  My updated code is in the above text.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49001/discussion-between-merlevede-and-user963070)

Comment: Added with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207722/android-displaying-bitmap/22208904?noredirect=1#comment33761109_22208904 gives entire solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a listView: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html
It shows a list of items, using an adapter to inflate elements. It is pretty simple to use.